# how to read npz file within zip files with numpy load

Tags: python, numpy, zip

I have many folders like year/month/date/data.npz file within a zip file called xyz.zip. I have tried using

```
rf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r')   ### load zip file
with rf.open(data_file_path) as target_f:
      result = np.load(target_f)
```

However, it did not work. I also tried

```
with io.BufferedReader(rf.open(data_file_path)) as target_f:
      result = np.load(target_f)
```

but it still reported error

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NpzFile' object has no attribute 'zip'" in <bound method NpzFile.__del__ of <numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x7f234ea1f510>> ignored
```

Is it possible to make it work? Or I have to manually unzip the file ....

Comment: There's no provision in the numpy code for that extra `zip` layer.  You'll have to handle that yourself.